# Soldering soft copper to hard fitting

Tags: plumbing, hvac, water, copper-tubing, soldering

I'm trying to solder a soft copper coil to a regular fitting and its not working, (I did already a lot of soldering and never had a problem)  is there any tips or tricks for soft copper? Do I have to work with it in a special way?
Thanks for any reply.

Comment: Does it fit nice and snug? There are different types (size schedules) of "soft copper".

Comment: @JimmyFix-it The schedules effect the wall thickness and inside diameter but not the outer diameter. 1/2" copper tube for plumbing is 0.625 (5/8) inches outer diameter no matter tube type such as K, L, M, etc. The copper tube handbook from copper.org can confirm this.

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: Check that the section of tubing is round. I have had trouble with copper tubing getting small flat areas on the outer edge of rolls, or getting deformed when cutting.  If its deformed that could explain the issue.

Comment: I use a [swaging tool](http://www.ebay.com/itm/PIPE-TUBE-SWAGE-SWAGING-EXPANDER-TOOL-SWAG-SWEDGING-EXPANDING-COPPER-TUBING-HVAC-/261642553383) to fit soft copper on HVAC systems. The sizes are not measured the same (id for hard copper pipe and od for soft copper). because of the small surface area in contact I use silver solder and flux. There are lower temperature solders but they wont hold up to vibration as well.

Comment: @isherwood 'Not working' I meant that the solder is'nt drawing in to the joint

Comment: @Mister Tea, of course you are correct; except for metric tubing. If a person were to attempt to solder 15mm tubing into a 1/2" type L fitting (5/8" O.D., 15.875mm) it could pose problems.

Comment: what is the solder you are using, what cleaning and prep are you doing, what is your heating tool, and what is the purpose of the item you are soldering?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is either the joint wasn't cleaned enough and/or not fluxed properly. I have had problems when my old tub of flux got dirt in it. When heating, the dirt burned and ruined the flux preventing a good solder joint. Check your flux and flux brush for dirt and replace or clean as needed. Then clean all of your joints thoroughly with one of those wire brush cleaners for copper tube or scotch bright.

Comment: I did a few joints after that one with the same flux and cleaned with brush and emery and all of them are good.

Comment: @aofkj As others have stated above, check for deformation of the tube ends.

Comment: also ... compared to the other joints that came out ok, were any of them as heavy as either of the 2 parts you are currently soldering? the more material, the more heat you would need on the larger part to form a equal temp between the two parts and a good bond.

Answer (score 0):

File the soldering points, and use a 1300W iron. If you can’t use leaded solder, go higher. Preheat the pipe for a minute.

Comment: Silver solder would be better than regular solder . however regular solder works well with a torch but it is not strong enough for HVAC. I know the OP did not say what this was for.

Comment: @EdBeal Yes, it’s also poisonous.

Comment: Silver solder is not poisonous and there is regular solder for plumbing ,,, I was not referring to electrical grade 60/40.

Comment: @EdBeal I meant regular solder was poisonous. I agree with you. In any case leaded solder should only be used inside enclosures.

Comment: What does go higher than leaded solder mean? Octane? Sorry, just joking. Please clarify. Also note there are different mixes with different melting points. As otherwise hinted here, clean the pipe with a brush or better yet a 800 grit wet paper. then use flux. VS. just "heating for a minute" heat the pipe just until you see the flux steam/bubble then introduce the solder to the point of pipe and iron with it applied to the pipe. Be sure both joints were prepared and heated evenly before applying solder.

Comment: @noybman Higher wattage iron. I’m not familiar with soldering with a gas torch.

Comment: ohhhhhh wattage. you posted it after the note on solder. Thats quite the gun, and about $1000 or higher. If a torch is an acceptable tool for the job it is far less expensive.

Comment: @noybman Doesn’t it get messy when doing it with a torch?

Comment: as I mentioned, depends on the job whether you can actually use a torch, but no, done right a torch is significantly easier and very clean (done right). The rule of thumb for soldering is to not use too much heat, and only heat for the length needed to do the job. If you're new to it, it doesn't hurt to buy some parts to waste, so you can practice. It's worth the cost for a first timer. And watching some youtube videos on the topic is totally acceptable. Soldering can be an art.

Comment: cavet.... buy a few cheap parts. DONT waste it on a $10valve or something. Just a few lengths of pipe or something

Comment: @noybman I’ve been looking for a gas torch for outdoor repairs for a while now - what kind of gas would you recommend? and what torch? Comments are not for this type of discussion, I’ll delete my irrelevant comments in a moment.

Comment: I'm not convinced yet (without OP editing their initial post) that this discussion is irrelevant.

Comment: @noybman Well, what gas torch do you recommend for OP’s application? My own interest in this extends to welding thin aluminium rods for machine casings, so if the answer covers that, you’re a golden goose.